# Cannot match literal dot with htaccess regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

The problem: I cannot figure out how to match a literal dot in my expression so I could rewrite query strings containing dots. First I tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\.\w]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I have a php script:

```
echo "url is: ".$_GET['url'];
```

which should, in theory, output anything that I write in my query. But for any query containing only letters and dots, my script always outputs:

```
url is: index.php
```

I've tried these expressions as well:

```
^(.+)$
^([.\w]+)$
```

And the result is the same.

So the question is: are my expressions wrong or does this have something to do with server's config?

Comment: That regex works as expected, it matches one or more characters from a set containing dots, alphanumeric characters and letters. Do you always get `index.php`, regardless of the path you request?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the regex with several online tools and it works. Yet I get the same result in two different webservers: no matter what the query is, php outputs 'index.php' and not what it should.

Comment: You do realize that Apache strips any query string from the URL before it gets to `RewriteRule`? Please give an example of the full URL you are inputting and the expected output desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is another request which is processed before the rule is applied, if I use a rule which matches less than `index.php` (e.g. `..` for matching `xy`), the result is as expected: `xy`. With more relaxing rules like `.*` or `.+` it fails. `x.*` works fine however.

You can add another condition to ignore requests like `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

This was tested/ debugged with:

```
<?php
printf("url is: %s <br>\n", htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url')));
echo "<pre>",htmlentities(print_R($_SERVER, 1));
```